# where to store twitter bootstrap while developing in eclipse

Tags: html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap for developing Web pages,Now I want to integrate this HTML code with jsp within eclipse. I was tried so by putting bootstrap folder in web-inf but it shows errors in bootstrap folder.So my problem is where I store twitter bootstrap folder so it can be use in eclipse project. 
t
Thanks in Advance
Sorry for English

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you've created a "Dynamic Web Project" bootstrap goes in the WebContent folder.

- WebContent

  - bootstrap

    - css
    - img
    - js
  - META-INF
  - WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is much simpler. You just put a bootstrap folder into project directory and then tell the path inside the HTML file. Like this: 
link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"